# Solving $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k2^k \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k2^k \binom{n}{k}$. By binomial theorem, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^k \binom{n}{k}=(1+x)^n$, I observe that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n kx^k \binom{n}{k}=\left (\sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^{k+1} \binom{n}{k} \right )'$, where ' indicates the first derivative.
But $\left (\sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^{k+1} \binom{n}{k} \right )'=(x(1+x)^n)'=(1+x)^{n-1}(1+x+nx)$.
Therefore

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n kx^k \binom{n}{k}=(1+x)^{n-1}(1+x+nx)$. Evaluating in $x=2$, I have the quantity $3^{n-1}(3+2n)$.
Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're working too hard. Using $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k2^k \binom{n}{k} = 2n\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} = 2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k \binom{n-1}{k} = 2n\cdot 3^{n-1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the (or at least on *a*) right track, though I believe you make a small algebraic mistake when you (effectively) say that $kx^k=(x^{k+1})'$; rather, $(x^{k+1})'=(k+1)x^k$  Instead, $kx^k=x\cdot((x^k)')$, but the rest of your approach should go through cleanly.  Once you have a result you believe is correct, just try plugging in various values of $n$ (remember to try $n=0$ and $n=1$!) to double-check.